# Is it possible to push a View Controller with a completion block?

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, pushviewcontroller

UINavigationController's documentation contains no `pushViewController` methods with a `completion:` parameter.

Comment: I got ur question but there is no way while push but present will have one like u expect or else u can do it didappear of pushed viewController

Answer (score -9, accepted):

I would go with @justMartin's answer . But below is another approach.

push animation take 0.3 seconds.So, if you want to run some function here after completion use performSelector after 0.3 seconds of delay.

```
[self performSelector:@selector(completedPushing:) withObject:nil afterDelay:.3];
```

**OR**
 After pushing the `new viewController` onto `navigation stack`,the `old viewController view` is removed from view hierarchy.so this results in call of `viewDidDisappear` on old ViewController.You can write your `completion` code there. don't forget to call `super` at some point of implementation of viewDidDisappear.

Comment: You can't say that for sure. Someone's iDevice could be running slowly, thus the animation may take longer.

Comment: The `performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:` suggestion isn't so great but the `viewDidDisappear` trick worked great for me even when it's a modal view controller that's being dismissed. Thanks for that 

Comment: this is an example of how things not should be done

Answer (score 67):

The better solution would be wrapping the push animation by an CATransaction and set the completionBlock. There's no need to deal with timings.

```
[CATransaction begin];
[CATransaction setCompletionBlock:^{
    //whatever you want to do after the push
}];
[[self navigationController] pushViewController:viewController animated:YES];
[CATransaction commit];
```

Comment: This is the best answer!!

Comment: At least using "slow animations" suggests that this isn't the right approach.

Comment: What about Swift 4? I couldn't find `CATransaction.begin()` method.

Comment: Also didn't work for me. Completion block is being executed before the animation has ended.

Answer (score 20):

justMartin's answer worked great for me. For those new to using swift API:

```
CATransaction.begin()
navigationController?.pushViewController(viewController, animated: true)
CATransaction.setCompletionBlock({ 
    //your post animation logic
})
CATransaction.commit()
```

Comment: Thanks, great tip

Comment: This seems to fail for me in case there is an animation that is started off as soon as the new viewcontroller loads. For example an activity indicator. I ended up creating properties in the new view controller and setting them before pushing, instead of trying to call a method in the new view controller from the old view controller once it is pushed.

Answer (score 15):

Solution with `CATransaction` is great but there is another way to do that. You can make your controller a delegate of `UINavigationController` and implement `didShowViewController` method:

```
class FooBarController: UIViewController, UINavigationControllerDelegate {
  func viewDidLoad() {
    self.navigationController?.delegate = self
  }

  func navigationController(navigationController: UINavigationController, didShowViewController viewController: UIViewController, animated: Bool) {
    // your awesome completion code here 
  }
}
```

This approach can be more convenient for your task

Comment: Ahhhhh !  Brilliant !

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if I understand correctly, but I pushed a view controller in a completion block as follows. In a table view controller, added the following line to the header file:

```
typedef void(^myCompletion)(BOOL);
```

Then in the class itself, added the following method:

```
-(void) myMethod:(myCompletion) compblock
{
    compblock(YES);
}
```

Now in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`, I called `myMethod` and in the completion block, pushed a view controller.

```
[self myMethod:^(BOOL finished) {
    if(finished){
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            DVSecondTableViewController *vc = [[DVSecondTableViewController alloc] init];
            [self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:YES];
        });
    }
}];
```

I'm not sure if it's okay to push view controllers outside of the main thread, so I embedded that call in a `dispatch_async()`.

Comment: the OP is asking how to send completion block to push ,not push the viewController from completion block. Just like presentViewController has completion block.

Answer (score 2):

Try using `-[UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator animateAlongsideTransitionInView:animation:completion:]`:

```
- (void)pushViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    if (!self.isPushing) {
        self.pushing = YES;
        [super pushViewController:viewController animated:animated];
        if (!self.transitionCoordinator) {
            self.pushing = NO;
        } else {
            [self.transitionCoordinator animateAlongsideTransition:nil completion:^(id<UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinatorContext> context) {
                self.pushing = NO;
            }];
        }
    }
}
```