# Segue cannot be passed from 1 controller to another by using Outlet property?

Tags: ios, ios5, ios7, ios6

I have two controller A and B

In B, I have a UISwitch IBOutlet.

when I use Segue from A,

`switch.on = YES` does not work.

If I declare another property in B , say switchvalue,

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSNumber* switchvalue;
```

I can pass the value to switchvalue.

Anyone has some clue? It is tedious that I cannot set property directly on controls.

Comment: IBOutlets are not set in time the segue is performed. So if you want to pass some information, you need to use an interim property and then set the outlet in viewDidLoad or viewWillAppear methods.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23403979/294884

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is impossible to set the value of an IBOutlet in `prepareForSegue`: because the outlets have not been created when this method is invoked. If you debug your code, you will see that the UISwitch value is nil when `prepareForSegue` is called.

As an alternative to setting an NSNumber property, you can try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18310396/how-to-execute-some-code-after-a-segue-is-done)

Comment: I add the normal property; when I debug, I also see that normal property is nil as well; but the value is passed to that normal property.

Comment: The string is nil because it does not have a value. You can set a value though. In the case of the IBOutlet you are not trying to set a value to the outlet but to a property of it. E.g you can do controller.string = @"a" but not controller.label.text = @"a" because  label is nil. So the text property cannot be changed. Thats the difference